# manage memory with bitmaps in android with recyclerView and Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview

I have this app that loads a bunch of image in a `recyclerView`. At first it loads only the text then downloads the images in the background. There are some instances that the app just freezes and will cause application not responding. I've look in the internet for solution like Lazy loading etc but I still get this `ANR`. Any suggestions out there? I'm using Parse.com as my server by the way.

Here is my `recyclerView` adapter. It looks really scary.

```
public class PostListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostListAdapter.PostViewHolder> {
    List<Post> postList;
    Context context;

    public PostListAdapter(List<Post> postList, Context context){
        this.postList = postList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public PostListAdapter.PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.post_card_layout, viewGroup, false);

        return new PostViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PostListAdapter.PostViewHolder postViewHolder, final int position) {
        postViewHolder.area.setText(postList.get(position).getArea());
        postViewHolder.userName.setText(postList.get(position).getUserName());
        postViewHolder.content.setText(postList.get(position).getContent());
        postViewHolder.vote.setText(String.format("%d", postList.get(position).getVotes()));
        postViewHolder.comment.setText(String.format("Comments: %d", postList.get(position).getComments()));

        if (postList.get(position).getUpVoteImage() != 0) {
            postViewHolder.upVote.setImageResource(postList.get(position).getUpVoteImage());
        } else {
            postViewHolder.upVote.setImageResource(R.drawable.upvote);
        }
        if (postList.get(position).getDownVoteImage() != 0) {
            postViewHolder.downVote.setImageResource(postList.get(position).getDownVoteImage());
        } else {
            postViewHolder.downVote.setImageResource(R.drawable.downvote);
        }

        ParseQuery<Vote> upVotes = ParseQuery.getQuery("Vote");
        upVotes.whereEqualTo("postId", postList.get(position).getObjectId());
        upVotes.whereEqualTo("userId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
        upVotes.whereEqualTo("voteType", "1");
        upVotes.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(final int i, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    ParseQuery<Vote> downVotes = ParseQuery.getQuery("Vote");
                    downVotes.whereEqualTo("postId", postList.get(position).getObjectId());
                    downVotes.whereEqualTo("userId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
                    downVotes.whereEqualTo("voteType", "0");
                    downVotes.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(int j, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                postList.get(position).setVotes(i - j);
                                postViewHolder.vote.setText(String.format("%d", i - j));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        ParseQuery<Comment> comments = ParseQuery.getQuery("Comment");
        comments.whereEqualTo("postId", postList.get(position).getObjectId());
//        comments.whereEqualTo("userId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
        comments.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(int i, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    postList.get(position).setComments(i);
                    postViewHolder.comment.setText(String.format("Comments: %d", postList.get(position).getComments()));
                }
            }
        });

        if (postList.get(position).getVoteType() == null) {
            postViewHolder.upVote.setClickable(false);
            postViewHolder.downVote.setClickable(false);
            ParseQuery<Vote> mainQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Vote");
            mainQuery.whereEqualTo("userId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
            mainQuery.whereEqualTo("postId", postList.get(position).getObjectId());
            mainQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Vote>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<Vote> vote, ParseException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        Msg.Toast(e.getMessage(), context);
                    } else {
                        if (vote.size() > 0) {
                            postList.get(position).setVoteType(vote.get(0).getVote());
                            postList.get(position).setVoteId(vote.get(0).getObjectId());
                            if (postList.get(position).getVoteType().equals("1")) {
                                postList.get(position).setUpVoteImage(R.drawable.upvoted);
                                postViewHolder.upVote.setImageResource(postList.get(position).getUpVoteImage());
                            } else {
                                postList.get(position).setDownVoteImage(R.drawable.downvoted);
                                postViewHolder.downVote.setImageResource(postList.get(position).getDownVoteImage());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    postViewHolder.upVote.setClickable(true);
                    postViewHolder.downVote.setClickable(true);
                }
            });
        }
        if (postList.get(position).getHasPhoto()) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = postViewHolder.content.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            postViewHolder.content.setLayoutParams(params);
            postViewHolder.photoThumb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            postViewHolder.content.setBackgroundResource(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            if (postList.get(position).getPhoto() == null) {
                postViewHolder.photoThumb.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
                postList.get(position).fetchIfNeededInBackground(new GetCallback<Post>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(Post photo, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            try {
                                postViewHolder.photoThumb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                postList.get(position).setPhoto(photo.getPhoto());
                                postViewHolder.photoThumb.setImageBitmap(postList.get(position).getPhoto());
                            } catch (Exception e1){
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                postViewHolder.photoThumb.setImageBitmap(postList.get(position).getPhoto());
            }
        } else {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = postViewHolder.content.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = 400;
            postViewHolder.content.setLayoutParams(params);
            postViewHolder.content.setText(postList.get(position).getContent());
            postViewHolder.photoThumb.setImageBitmap(null);
            postViewHolder.photoThumb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        postViewHolder.upVote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                upvotePost(postViewHolder, position);
            }
        });
        postViewHolder.downVote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                downvotePost(postViewHolder, position);
            }
        });

        postViewHolder.comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, ViewCommentActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("author", postList.get(position).getUserName());
                i.putExtra("authorId", postList.get(position).getUserId());
                i.putExtra("content", postList.get(position).getContent());
                i.putExtra("postId", postList.get(position).getObjectId());
                if (postList.get(position).getHasPhoto()) {
                    i.putExtra("photo", postList.get(position).getPhoto());
                }
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return postList.size();
    }

    public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView area;

        protected TextView userName;
        protected TextView content;
        protected TextView vote;
        protected TextView comment;
        protected ImageView photoThumb, upVote, downVote;
        public PostViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            area = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvArea);
            userName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvUserName);
            content = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
            vote = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvLike);
            comment = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvComment);
            photoThumb = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto);
            upVote = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivUpVote);
            downVote = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivDownVote);
        }

    }

    private void downvotePost(final PostViewHolder postViewHolder, final int position) {
        postViewHolder.upVote.setClickable(false);
        postViewHolder.downVote.setClickable(false);
        if (postList.get(position).getVoteType() != null) {
            if (postList.get(position).getVoteType().equals("0")) {
                ParseQuery<Vote> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Vote");
                query.getInBackground(postList.get(position).getVoteId(), new GetCallback<Vote>() {
                    public void done(Vote vote, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            vote.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {
                                        int newVote = postList.get(position).getVotes() + 1;
                                        postList.get(position).setVotes(newVote);
                                        postViewHolder.vote.setText(String.format("%d", newVote));
                                        postList.get(position).setDownVoteImage(R.drawable.downvote);
                                        postViewHolder.downVote.setImageResource(postList.get(position).getDownVoteImage());
                                        postList.get(position).setVoteType(null);
                                    } else {
                                        Msg.Toast(e.getMessage(), context);
                                    }
                                    postViewHolder.upVote.setClickable(true);
                                    postViewHolder.downVote.setClickable(true);
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Msg.Toast(e.getMessage(), context);
                            postViewHolder.upVote.setClickable(true);
                            postViewHolder.downVote.setClickable(true);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                ParseQuery<Vote> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Vote");
                query.getInBackground(postList.get(position).getVoteId(), new GetCallback<Vote>() {
                    public void done(Vote vote, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            vote.setVote("0");
                            vote.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {
                                        int newVote = postList.get(position).getVotes() - 2;
                                        postList.get(position).setVotes(newVote);
                                        postList.get(position).setVoteType("0");
                                        postList.get(position).setUpVoteImage(R.drawable.upvote);
                                        postList.get(position).setDownVoteImage(R.drawable.downvoted);
                                        postViewHolder.vote.setText(String.format("%d", newVote));

                                        postViewHolder.downVote.setImageResource(postList.get(position).getDownVoteImage());
                                        postViewHolder.upVote.setImageResource(postList.get(position).getUpVoteImage());
                                    } else {
                                        Msg.Toast(e.getMessage(), context);
                                    }
                                    postViewHolder.upVote.setClickable(true);
                                    postViewHolder.downVote.setClickable(true);
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Msg.Toast(e.getMessage(), context);
                            postViewHolder.upVote.setClickable(true);
                            postViewHolder.downVote.setClickable(true);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            final Vote vote = new Vote();
            vote.setPostId(postList.get(position).getObjectId());
            vote.setUserId(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
            vote.setVote("0");
            vote.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        ParseQuery<Post> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Post");
                        query.getInBackground(postList.get(position).getObjectId(), new GetCallback<Post>() {
                            public void done(Post updatePost, ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    int newVote = postList.get(position).getVotes() - 1;
                                    postList.get(position).setVotes(newVote);
                                    postList.get(position).setVoteId(vote.getObjectId());
                                    postList.get(position).setVoteType("0");
                                    postList.get(position).setUpVoteImage(R.drawable.upvote);
                                    postList.get(position).setDownVoteImage(R.drawable.downvoted);
                                    postViewHolder.vote.setText(String.format("%d", newVote));
                                    postViewHolder.downVote.setImageResource(postList.get(position).getDownVoteImage());
                                    postViewHolder.upVote.setImageResource(postList.get(position).getUpVoteImage());
                                } else {
                                    postList.get(position).setDownVoteImage(R.drawable.downvoted);
                                    postViewHolder.downVote.setImageResource(postList.get(position).getDownVoteImage());
                                    Msg.Toast(e.getMessage(), context);
                                }
                                postViewHolder.upVote.setClickable(true);
                                postViewHolder.downVote.setClickable(true);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Msg.Toast(e.getMessage(), context);
                    }
                    postViewHolder.upVote.setClickable(true);
                    postViewHolder.downVote.setClickable(true);
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private void upvotePost(final PostViewHolder postViewHolder, final int position) {
        postViewHolder.upVote.setClickable(false);
        postViewHolder.downVote.setClickable(false);
        if (postList.get(position).getVoteType() != null) {
            if (postList.get(position).getVoteType().equals("1")) {
                ParseQuery<Vote> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Vote");
                query.getInBackground(postList.get(position).getVoteId(), new GetCallback<Vote>() {
                    public void done(Vote vote, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            vote.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {
                                        int newVote = postList.get(position).getVotes() - 1;
                                        postList.get(position).setVotes(newVote);
                                        postViewHolder.vote.setText(String.format("%d", newVote));
                                        postViewHolder.upVote.setImageResource(R.drawable.upvote);
                                        postList.get(position).setVoteType(null);
                                    } else {
                                        Msg.Toast(e.getMessage(), context);
                                    }
                                    postViewHolder.upVote.setClickable(true);
                                    postViewHolder.downVote.setClickable(true);
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            postViewHolder.upVote.setClickable(true);
                            postViewHolder.downVote.setClickable(true);
                            Msg.Toast(e.getMessage(), context);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                ParseQuery<Vote> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Vote");
                query.getInBackground(postList.get(position).getVoteId(), new GetCallback<Vote>() {
                    public void done(Vote vote, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            vote.setVote("1");
                            vote.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {
                                        int newVote = postList.get(position).getVotes() + 2;
                                        postList.get(position).setVotes(newVote);
                                        postList.get(position).setVoteType("1");
                                        postList.get(position).setUpVoteImage(R.drawable.upvoted);
                                        postList.get(position).setDownVoteImage(R.drawable.downvote);
                                        postViewHolder.vote.setText(String.format("%d", newVote));
                                        postViewHolder.upVote.setImageResource(postList.get(position).getUpVoteImage());
                                        postViewHolder.downVote.setImageResource(postList.get(position).getDownVoteImage());
                                    } else {
                                        Msg.Toast(e.getMessage(), context);
                                    }
                                    postViewHolder.upVote.setClickable(true);
                                    postViewHolder.downVote.setClickable(true);
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            postViewHolder.upVote.setClickable(true);
                            postViewHolder.downVote.setClickable(true);
                            Msg.Toast(e.getMessage(), context);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            final Vote vote = new Vote();
            vote.setPostId(postList.get(position).getObjectId());
            vote.setUserId(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
            vote.setVote("1");
            vote.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        ParseQuery<Post> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Post");
                        query.getInBackground(postList.get(position).getObjectId(), new GetCallback<Post>() {
                            public void done(Post updatePost, ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    int newVote = postList.get(position).getVotes() + 1;
                                    postList.get(position).setVotes(newVote);
                                    postList.get(position).setVoteId(vote.getObjectId());
                                    postList.get(position).setVoteType("1");
                                    postList.get(position).setUpVoteImage(R.drawable.upvoted);
                                    postList.get(position).setDownVoteImage(R.drawable.downvote);
                                    postViewHolder.vote.setText(String.format("%d", newVote));
                                    postViewHolder.upVote.setImageResource(postList.get(position).getUpVoteImage());
                                    postViewHolder.downVote.setImageResource(postList.get(position).getDownVoteImage());
                                } else {
                                    postViewHolder.upVote.setImageResource(R.drawable.upvoted);
                                    Msg.Toast(e.getMessage(), context);
                                }
                                postViewHolder.upVote.setClickable(true);
                                postViewHolder.downVote.setClickable(true);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        postViewHolder.upVote.setClickable(true);
                        postViewHolder.downVote.setClickable(true);
                        Msg.Toast(e.getMessage(), context);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you load the info in the mainthread you will get a 'application not responding' , try using asyncktask to load the info in memory before you load the info.